# Не могу написать программу в Python, которая считывает целые числа из списка и выводит из него только чётные в обратном порядке

Tags: python

```
numbers = [7, 14, 3, 18, 21, 10, 9, 6]
print('Исходный список: ', numbers)

for i in range(len(numbers)-1, -1, -1):
  if numbers[i] % 2 == 0:
    print('Отсортированный список: ', numbers[i])
```

Comment: Найденное, надо же куда то сохранять. Потом список развернуть, а уже потом выводить. Сейчас у вас if вообще ничего не делает

Comment: Хотя, если добавите 4 пробела перед последней строкой, все заработает.

Comment: @SwaD, а в теории этот пользователь может быть ботом?

Comment: @NNL993 От внесенной правки суть меняется. Не стоит менять код

Comment: @Nymos Все может быть ¯\\(ツ)/¯

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @SwaD, просто это глупо, не может быть такое, что программист такого уровня, который знает, что такое шаг и ошибается в 4 пробелах, ну это глупо. Так же, ник и фотографии выглядит подозрительно...

Comment: 4 пробела добавляла, но тогда на каждое число идет отдельная строка с текстом "Отсортированный список"

Comment: уровень у меня очень низкий, к слову

Comment: @ЕленаШикова, а что насчет моего способа, который я вам скинул в ответ)?

Comment: попробуйте скопировать мой код снизу))))

Comment: Nymos , спасибо, все отлично работает

Comment: ну тогда нажмите на галочку, чтобы потвердеть, что я вам помог)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать отдельный  пустой список, для того, чтобы сохранять в нем  чётные числа. Так же в твоем коде `if` вообще ничего не делает, что выдает ошибку в коде. Вот исправленный код:

```py
numbers = [7, 14, 3, 18, 21, 10, 9, 6]
print('Исходный список: ', numbers)
z=[] #пустой список
for i in range(len(numbers)-1, -1, -1):
  if numbers[i] % 2 == 0:
      z.append(numbers[i]) # сюда добавляю четные числа
print('Отсортированный список: ', z)
```

Comment: `for x in reversed(numbers): if x % 2 == 0: ...`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я живу в индии и мне платят за строчки кода

Comment: Я имел в виду что не нужны индексы чтобы перебрать список в обратном направлении. Число строк останется тем же.

Comment: @Nymos если строки кода, тогда надо `len(numbers)` в переменную вынести и внутри if `numbers[i]` тоже сначала в переменную положить, а потом ее в аппенд, так будет +2 строки. А если еще и по рекомендациям разделить участки кода пустыми строками, так кодовая база процентов на 50 увеличится :)

Comment: ого, я даже не знал... Если надо будет программировать тест для беременности, то буду использовать ваш совет. Спасибо @SwaD

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно с помощью `filter`:

```py
numbers = [7, 14, 3, 18, 21, 10, 9, 6]
print('Исходный список: ', numbers)

print('Отсортированный список: ', list(filter(lambda i: i % 2 == 0, numbers))[::-1])
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

Comment: Это я еще не проходила, но спасибо